# Sparklyr problem with tidy() function in context of ml_generalized_linear_regression() compared to ml_logistic_regression()

Tags: model, logistic-regression, sparklyr, tidy

I am trying to build a model through sparklyr.

I started with exploratory analysis and then data cleaning (one hot encoding mostly).

I then built a logistic regression model with a binary outcome variable (0,1) using ml_logistic_regression which worked well and I was able to use the tidy() function to get a tibble of coefficients.

However, I wished to obtain the standard deviations for the model so I went on to use ml_generalized_linear_regression(). This model also worked but it will not let me create the tibble due to an error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 38, 0
```

Clearly there is a difference in the number of rows in my arguments for the model but I'm not sure why that is the case.

One hot encoding method

````
dataset = mutate(dataset, var_1 = ifelse(var == 'x', 1,0), var_2 = ifelse(var == 'y', 1,0)```

model building method

```model <-dataset %>%  ml_logistic_regression(binaryoutcome ~ var1 + continuousvar, family = 'binomial')
summary(model) 
tidy(model)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 38, 0```
````

Comment: I am running into the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem as well